# how to retrieve data from json when user selects the date from date picker option in my application

Tags: android

My application contains date picker option. When ever user select the particular date then data which is present on that day should display on tab content. I am successful in parsing the data from JSON but I am not getting how to parse the data with date. pls help me. thank you

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setCurrentDateOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();


    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // vehicle Tab
    TabSpec vehicleSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(VEHICLE_SPEC);
    // Tab Icon
    vehicleSpec.setIndicator(VEHICLE_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.v));
    Intent vehicleIntent = new Intent(this, vehicle.class);
    // Tab Content
    vehicleSpec.setContent(vehicleIntent);
 // driver Tab
    TabSpec driverSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(DRIVER_SPEC);
    // Tab Icon
    driverSpec.setIndicator(DRIVER_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dr));
    Intent driverIntent = new Intent(this, driver.class);
    // Tab Content
    driverSpec.setContent(driverIntent);
 // ignition Tab
    TabSpec ignitionSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(IGNITION_SPEC);
    // Tab Icon
    ignitionSpec.setIndicator(IGNITION_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.i));
    Intent ignitionIntent = new Intent(this, ignition.class);
    // Tab Content
    ignitionSpec.setContent(ignitionIntent);
 // activity Tab
    TabSpec activitySpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(ACTIVITY_SPEC);
    // Tab Icon
    activitySpec.setIndicator(ACTIVITY_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.activity));
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, activity.class);
    // Tab Content
    activitySpec.setContent(activityIntent);

    // speed Tab
    TabSpec speedSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(SPEED_SPEC);
    speedSpec.setIndicator(SPEED_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d));
    Intent speedIntent = new Intent(this, speed.class);
    speedSpec.setContent(speedIntent);

    // idle Tab
    TabSpec idleSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(IDLE_SPEC);
    idleSpec.setIndicator(IDLE_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.idle));
    Intent idleIntent = new Intent(this, idle.class);
    idleSpec.setContent(idleIntent);
    TabSpec distanceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(DISTANCE_SPEC);
    distanceSpec.setIndicator(DISTANCE_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s));
    Intent distanceIntent = new Intent(this, distance.class);
    distanceSpec.setContent(distanceIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(distanceSpec); // Adding distance tab
    tabHost.addTab(idleSpec); // Adding idle tab
    tabHost.addTab(speedSpec); // Adding speed tab
    tabHost.addTab(ignitionSpec); // Adding ignition tab
    tabHost.addTab(driverSpec); // Adding driver tab
    tabHost.addTab(vehicleSpec); // Adding vehicle tab
    tabHost.addTab(activitySpec); // Adding activity tab
    TabWidget tabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    final int tabChildrenCount = tabWidget.getChildCount();
    View currentView;
    for (int i = 0; i < tabChildrenCount; i++) {
        currentView = tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams currentLayout =
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) currentView.getLayoutParams();
        currentLayout.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
    tabWidget.requestLayout();

}
private void addListenerOnButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dbtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dbtn1);

    dbtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }
    });
}
private void setCurrentDateOnView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));

    // set current date into datepicker
    dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

}
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
           .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
           .append(" "));

        // set selected date into datepicker also
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

    }
};
```

}

my json........it is updated daily in server

```
{"results" :[{"id":"34492","vehicle_name":"Innova","driver_name":"Mahesh","coordinates":"17.3510,78.5561","location_name":"Sai Soba Construction, Central Bank Colony, LB Nagar, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh 500074, India","speed":"2","posted_on":"2013-04-24 10:33:40","created_on":"2013-04-24 10:33:53"}
```

Comment: Can you show date picker code?

Comment: Your app contains date picker functionality as you said, so where is that part of code?

Comment: You have already set `datePickerListener`. So what's the problem? In that you can call the function for retrieving data from json using `tvDisplayDate.getText()` as parameter to it.

Comment: i am getting json data when i click tab in app..........but i have to retrieve data  according to date selected by user in my tab content.....how to implement

Comment: Put the code from onClick of tab to inside datePickerListener

Comment: can pls provide me the sample example.i am new to android.thanku

Answer (score 0):

you can find help regarding DatePicker from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/) and TImePicker from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/)

Than make date in your desire format as per in your JSON (from [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=406))

now you can easily filter your data. Thanks!

Comment: i have to place date picker code in AndroidTabAndListView class when ever user select the date that data which is present in json on that date should be shown in tab content...............